# copying a document from sharepoint explorer view is updating the file timestamp

Tags: explorer-view, copy-and-paste, open-with-explorer, timestamp

I am trying to copy documents from SharePoint using Explorer view.

Once the copy is completed from SharePoint to my local machine folder, the file time stamp is being updated with my id as last modified.

Please advice how I can retain the initial author and timestamp